Google sheets App script copy and paste with condition
An issue has been bothering me.
My Google Sheets has two columns of data, G and L. The data in G changes every 5 minutes, while the data in L does not change.
The current requirement is to use a app script trigger to check every five minutes: if the G column of the same row is greater than the L column, then copy the data in G column to the L column of the same row.
How can I implement this in the app script? Thanks!

Currently, I can only copy the entire G column data to the L column every five minutes, but I can't compare them.
function copyGtoL() {
  const x = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const y = x.getSheetByName('data');
  y.getRange('G4:G').copyTo(y.getRange(12, 4), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}


Use conditional statement
I integrated the conditional statement to compare the two columns and used a for loop to apply the condition to every row.
Modified code:
function copyGtoL() {
  const x = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const y = x.getSheetByName('data');

  const columnG = y.getRange(4, 7, y.getLastRow() - 3, 1).getValues(); 
  const columnL = y.getRange(4, 12, y.getLastRow() - 3, 1).getValues(); 
  
  for (let i = 0; i < columnG.length; i++) {
    if (columnG[i][0] > columnL[i][0]) {
      y.getRange(i + 4, 12).setValue(columnG[i][0]);
    }
  }
}

NOTE: Please use a Time-driven installable trigger to meet the requirement of 5 minutes update.
Result:

References:

Conditional statements
For loop


Feel free to try it on your end and let me know how it turns out.

Hi my friend. Perfect! Thanks for your help! I am learning your code, it is really great!

@stacker Thank you for your reply. If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer

Accepted, thanks!!
